# Callback Api VK Дублируются сообщения

Tags: python, вконтакте, flask

Есть скрипт на хостинге

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

def processing():

    #Распаковываем json из пришедшего POST-запроса

    data = json.loads(request.data)

    #Вконтакте в своих запросах всегда отправляет поле типа

    if 'type' not in data.keys():
        return 'not vk'

    if data['type'] == 'confirmation':
        return confirmation_token

    elif data['type'] == 'message_new':

        session = vk.Session(access_token=token_group)
        api = vk.API(session)

        ## Делаем что угодно


    return 'ok'
```

Так вот vk дублирует запросы хотя решенеие проблемы вернуть 'ok' что я и делаю только это не решает проблему. В чем может быть загвоздка?

Answer (score 0):

В админке группы в настройках Callback API проверьте историю запросов. Все удачные запросы там описаны, все неудачные тоже (и можно посмотреть, что вернул сервер).

Запросы повторяются только если ответ не соответствовал требованиям (тело `ok` и код 200). Проблема на вашей стороне, просто проверьте.

Comment: На стороне VK он видит их как отправленные! А вот логи с сервера такие --- uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 296] during POST---  ---SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request  --- Суть в чем у меня скрипт работает порядка 10 секунд я так понял ошибка в том что VK закрывает соединение или что-то в этом роде, как решить ее я хз

Comment: @Xstyle71 у них таймаут около 20 секунд, вроде бы. Вполне должно хватить для вас. Я обычно в таких случаях сразу ответ возвращаю, а потом запускаю долгую работу. Можете асинхронно начать выполнение задач, и сразу вернуть ответ ВК.

Comment: Не, смысл в том что после 10 секунд я возвращаю ответ юзеру написавшему боту сообщение! Если вернуть сразу то скрипт прерывается.Получается мой скрипт типа генерирует какие то ошибки, хотя в pycharm  их нет, и в vk  возвращается не только ok.

Comment: Я сейчас сделал тест попросил вернуть ок после банального ответа! респонс 1 секунда, 20 минут вк заново отправли запрос на сервер хотя я не писал сообщение боту.

Comment: @Xstyle71 проверьте в админке, считает ли ВК ваш запрос корректным, и если нет, то почему.

Comment: На запрос в VK в неудавшихся такая ошибка **Error: HTTP response code said error. Attempt 2/5** На хостинге **[27/Jun/2018:16:04:23 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "curl/7.38.0**

Comment: Настроил на простом коде, ответ на любой вопрос 1ой фразой все норм!(Нужно было SSL сертификат добавить) Сейчас на более сложном скрипте такая ошибка **Error: Timeout was reached. Attempt 3/5**

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена!

1. Нужно сделать SSL сертификат для Flask можно заимпортить бибилиотечку:
   from flask_sslify import SSLify
   app = Flask(**name**)
   sslify = SSLify(app)
2. Скрипт работал больше 8 секунд, в VK сказали что нужно дать отлик в течечении 10 сек. ПРоблему решил оптимизацией скрипта и укладыванием в этот временной диапазон!

Answer (score 0):

ВК дублирует сообщения, потому что Ваш код не отправляет в ответ на Callback "ok" из-за полученных ошибок в коде

В разработке кода это неизбежно, поэтому я советую Вам добавить обработчик ошибок

Можете добавить в конец такой код

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def handler(e):
    # уведомляете админа об ошибке
    # ...
    # возвращаете ВК ok
    return 'ok'
```

Тогда ВК даже при ошибках будет слать Callback-и только один единственный раз

Comment: Выглядит очень сомнительно...